# Браузеры и новые вкладки

Tags: html

На сайте имеются каталоги. Так вот у ссылок в каталогах прописан атрибут  target=blank
 Вот мы открываем одну ссылку, открывается новая Вкладка, открываем вторую и вместо второй вкладки обновляется вкладка открытая первой..

т.е вроде как браузер не дает открыть много вкладок( как разрешить это?

Comment: Наверное, это специфичное поведение браузера - дабы не плодить кучу в кладок с одинаковым URL. Как вариант, можно попробовать добавлять что-то типа `timestep` или какое-нибудь случайное число к ссылке, но это уже с использованием JS

Answer (score 1):

Правильно будет target="_blank"